# How to delete[] decayed array?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator, pass-by-value

How to delete an array declared with `new` if I don't have access to the original pointer x? Let's assume, I know the array size.

For example, if I write the following code:

```
void enlarge(int * x) {
    int * tmp = new int[20];
    memcpy(tmp, x, 10*sizeof(int));
    delete[] x; //?
    x = tmp;
}

int main() {
    int * x = new int[10];
    enlarge(x);
    delete[] x; //??? free(): double free detected in tcache 2
}
```

1. Would `delete[]` within `enlarge()` function know how much memory to free?
2. Apparently, `delete[]` within `main()` results in an error during execution. Why? How to avoid it?

Comment: `enlarge` should probably return a new pointer, and then can be called as `x = enlarge(x)`. Otherwise, you are deleting old memory and leaking new. The caller can no longer access either. Better still, do yourself a favor and use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: Yes, it does. Preferrably you'd leave freeing the data to a smart pointer though: `void enlarge(std::unique_ptr<int[]> & x) { auto tmp = std::make_unique<int[]>(20); memcpy(tmp.get(), x, 10 * sizeof(int)); x = std::move(tmp); }`  `int main() {auto x = std::make_unique<int[]>(10); enlarge(x);}`

Comment: ***Apparently, delete[] within main() results in an error during execution. Why? How to avoid it?*** Because you pass `x` by value. `void enlarge(int * x) {` copies x and enlarges it freeing the original memory location but not changing `x` in main which after running enlarge `x` in `int main()` points to the original location which you attempt to free a second time in `int main()`

Comment: Incidentally, the concept of array decay is irrelevant here. It doesn’t happen in your code anyway: all variables you declare of *pointer*, not array, type.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do you mean that _array decay_ refers only to arrays declared statically, e.g. with `int x[10]`?

Comment: @user1079505 *"Do you mean that* array decay *refers only to arrays declared statically, e.g. with `int x[10]`?"* -- Inaccurate. Array decay occurs only when you have an object whose type is an array. If you declare `int x[10]` then the type of `x` is an array. If you declare `int * x` then the type of `x` is a pointer. A pointer cannot be subject to the decay **from an array to a pointer** because 1) a pointer is not an array and 2) a pointer is already a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `enlarge` produces a memory leak because the pointer `x` declared in main is passed to the function by value. That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer `x`. Changing within the function the copy leaves the original pointer `x` declared in main unchanged.

As a result this statement in main

```
delete[] x;
```

invokes undefined behavior because the memory pointed to by the pointer `x` was already freed in the function `enlarge`.

You need to pass the pointer by reference like

```
void enlarge(int * &x) {
    int * tmp = new int[20];
    memcpy(tmp, x, 10*sizeof(int));
    delete[] x;
    x = tmp;
}
```

Pay attention to that instead of raw pointers it is better to use standard container `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to delete an array declared with new if I don't have access to the original pointer x?

You cannot. In order to delete a dynamic array, you must know the pointer to the first element of that array - i.e. the pointer that was returned by `new`.

> Would delete[] within enlarge() function know how much memory to free?

Yes.

> Apparently, delete[] within main() results in an error during execution. Why?

Because the same pointer was already deleted in `enlarge`. If you delete a pointer more than once, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> How to avoid it?

Don't delete a pointer more than once.

P.S. `enlarge` leaks the array that it allocates. Don't use new and delete. Use RAII containers such as `std::vector` instead.

---

> Ah, so array decay affects only statically declared arrays

Array decay is an implicit conversion of an expression of array type to a pointer to first element. The type of `x` is `int*`. That is not an array type. `int*` is a pointer type. As it isn't an array type, it doesn't implicitly convert to a pointer to first element. `x` is already the pointer to the first element.

Comment: Ah, so array decay affects only statically declared arrays, and the dynamically declared ones can be always deleted with `delete[]`, for as long as I have some pointer to the first element?

Answer (score 1):

The `delete` call within `enlarge` is deleting the `int *x` declared in `main`, as you're simply passing the pointer to a new function. This is why `delete[] x` in `main` gives you a double free; that pointer doesn't exist anymore.

**Update**: I should clarify that when you pass a pointer by value, you're effectively copying it. `delete`ing a copy of a pointer also `delete`s the original pointer.